# Inverse of the Jacobi-Matrix of the power flow equations

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I am looking for a closed-form solution for the inverse $J_p^{-1}(v)$ of the following matrix:

$J_p(v) = \text{diag}(v)Y+\text{diag}(Yv)$,

where $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is arbitrary and $Y=Y^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is known.

Background: The power flow equations for a DC-Microgrid are given by $p=v\circ Yv$, where $Y$ is the nodal admittance matrix and $\circ$ the Hadamard product.

Does somebody have some hints or ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Do we know anything else about $Y$, such as invertibility, positive (or negative) definiteness, or entries being nonnegative?

Comment: Yes, it holds that $Y = Y_s + A^\top Y_l A$, where $Y_s$ and $Y_l$ are positive definite under mild assumptions on the power system. The matrix $A$ is the incidence matrix of the power system and thus we can say that $Y$ is positive definite under mild (standard) assumptions to the power system.

Comment: @Trb2 Thanks for the input. $Y$ has full rank, if there is at least one shunt element, otherwise ($Y_s=0$) $\text{rank}(Y)=n-1$ [Reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7962226).   
Therefore, I agree with you that $Y$ is positive definite under mild assumptions. 

More information about $Y$: The diagonal elements of $Y$ are strictly positive and the non-diagonal elements are non-positive.